# Cannot login to GeoServer after enabling proxy authentication

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, authentication, proxy, geoserver-security

Following [this tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/tutorials/httpheaderproxy/index.html) I activated proxy authentication on GeoServer for listing all available layers using REST API from another application. Now I can not login from the main window http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/ . It says *"Invalid username/password combination."*. I have not changed password or done anything after the proxy activation.

Comment: You will need to supply the correct header to log in as well as the user name and password. It is unlikely that your browser knows to do this

Comment: With rest it works. But I want to access the administration interface to change the layers.

Comment: Then you need to set the authentication header in your requests to the GUI

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: depends on your browser I guess